# Why isn't Text Draw working anymore?

Tags: texture-painting

I am testing texture painting, I was working fine with TextDraw paint

I tried to test/try Mask brush but now TextDraw isn't working anymore

I think I am missing something obvious here

any help

Comment: I assume you were using *Mask* option from Slots tab. After or before unchecking its box you should also unlink that image used as a mask (I'm not sure why this should be done).